# Set notation with recursive requirement

Tags: metric-spaces, notation

Given a set $X$ of points in some metric space, and a scalar $b$, let us define for a representative point $x \in X$ its "cluster" as follows:

$C_x$ is a set of points in $X$, which

1. Contains $x$ as an element.
2. Any pair $y, z$ of points in $C_x$ holds $dist(y, z) \le b$

---

All I want is to write some closed form notation of this set, such as

$C'_x = \{x' \in X| dist(x', x) \le b\}$, which is not the group I want!, It is just of the notation form I am looking for, for lack of better words.

I want a notation for $C_x$, only with the correct condition stated in 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reiterating/collating comments:

Given choices of $x,b,X$ there is no unique set satisfying your desired conditions.  The properties you speak of are just saying that the set contains $x$ and the [diameter](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedDiameter.html) of the set is at most $b$, however there are potentially infinitely many sets with diameter $b$ or less containing $x$.

For instance, with $x=1,b=1,X=\Bbb R$ and the usual topology, we have that $[0,1],[1,2],[0.5,1.5],\{\frac{1}{n}~:~n\in\Bbb N\}, \{1\}$ and many others satisfy your desired conditions (*any two elements in $[0,1]$ for instance being at distance at most $1$ apart*), $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$ both being "maximal" in the sense that no additional elements could be added to either while maintaining the desired properties.  This is unlike the definition of a ball which is in fact unique (*noting that we specified that $x$ must be the center of the ball*).

You may be interested to note that balls of radius $r$ do have diameter $2r$, so if you did want a specific unique choice, you can specify that $x$ must be the center somehow and the set be maximal in which case your $C_x$ would have been $B_{b/2}(x)$ the (*closed*) ball of radius $\frac{b}{2}$ centered around $x$.